# The program with a 2d array does not work correctly

Tags: arrays, c, turtle-graphics

The essence of the program is that I set the size of the array with two numbers, then I use the input "v", "<", ">" , "^". I set the direction where the turtle will move. When checking the code, with the help of tests, I realized that my program was not working correctly when I wrote in terminal

```
5 15
o
v
o
v
o
v
o
>
v
o
>
o
>
^
o
^
o
^
o
^
o
>
>
o
v
o
v
o
v
o
v
o
^
^
>
o
>
^
o
^
<
o
>
>
>
o
v
o
v
o
v
o
v
o
^
^
>
o
>
^
o
^
<
o
v
v
>
v
o
v
>
o
>
>
v
o
v
o
v
o
v
v
o
x
```

When entering, i have this:

[image: screenshot1]

But,  the correct result is:

[image: screenshot2]

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int hor;
int vert;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int i, a;
char znacka = 'z';
scanf("%d%d", &vert, &hor);
char* arr = (char*)malloc(vert * hor * sizeof(char));
    
    arr[x *vert + y] = 'o';
    for ( i = 0; i < vert; i++ )
    {
        for( a = 0; a < hor; a++ )
        arr[ i * vert + a ] = '.';
    }

    while( znacka != 'x' )
{
    scanf("%c", &znacka);  
    if ( znacka == '^' ) x--; 
    
    else if ( znacka == 'v' ) x++; 
    else if ( znacka == '>' ) y++; 
    else if ( znacka == '<' ) y--; 
    else if ( znacka == 'o' ) arr[x *vert + y] = 'o'; 
    
    if(y < 0)
        y = vert - 1; 
    else if(y > vert)
        y = 0;
    
    if(x < 0)
        x = hor - 1;
    else if(x > hor)
        x = 0;
}
    for ( i = 0; i < vert; i++ )
{
    for( a = 0; a < hor; a++ )
    {
        printf("%c",arr [i *vert + a]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
free(arr);
return 0;    
}
```

What could be the problem?
Thank you for your attention and help!

I can't figure out what my problem is.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This looks like an assignment, so it doesn't help you for me to simply provide a final-worked example.  So I'm just giving "power-hints".

The indexing into the grid is not correct, it looks to be transposing `x` & `y`:

```
arr[x *vert + y] = 'o';   // produces a rotated grid (I think)
```

If you have an array of size `vert * hor` that represents a `hor` by `vert` grid (i.e: width by length), then the index into the grid at `x,y` is:

```
x + ( y * width )
```

Re-factoring into the program:

```
arr[ x + ( y * hor ) ] = 'o';
```

Where the top-left cell is at `( 0, 0 )` and the bottom-right at `( hor-1, vert-1 )`.

You need to *firstly* ensure that the output is being drawn correctly, otherwise any test-result is moot.

A good start at debugging might be to define a 7x13 array, and fill it with rows of '0000000', '1111111', ... 'ccccccc'.  Then use this to check the grid printing functions.  Once this array prints out OK, then try drawing an `x` to `(4,7)` and verify it's in the centre, etc. etc.

Right now you have a bunch of stuff that's not quite right, so you need to establish a base-line of what works, and then keep fixing various code blocks from there.

Comment: Of course, the grid-printing part also needs to be adjusted.  And that part provides a good clue that the indexing is wrong, too.  It the maximum value taken by `i` and `a` in the loop nest, it the array element indexed is `arr[(vert - 1) * vert + hor - 1]`, or, equivalently, `arr[vert * vert - vert + hor -1]`.  What we expect should be `arr[vert * hor - 1]`, which is not equivalent.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers, this is really a task :) ,I will definitely check and do everything you wrote, thank you!